# Stuck with image import using magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento, csv, import, magento-1.9

I m importing magento product with native magento import profile. All the product imported successfully but image is not imported.
I have also put the images on media/import folder and in csv write image name like /image1.jpg but it still giving null image after successfully imported csv.

what will be the issue please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have done trying below things

- All required images are placed in media/import
- setting 777 permission to media/import
- Putting "/." in your csv coloumn
  "image", "_media_image"("thumbnail", "small_image" if you want to)
- Putting "_media_attribute_id"="88" & "_media_is_disabled"=0 on every image row aaccordingly.